# How to test for my Javascript callback with Jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I need to test if specific methods are called when user scrolls the window to a certain point. In my source code I have windows listener attached, something like:

```
$(window).on("scroll.singleJob",function(e)
{       
    // code here, check if the window is scrolled past certain point etc. and then I need to call this method
            LozengesPanel.makeFixed();              
}
```

Now, in my Jasmine test I'm trying to confirm that the method is being called when the window is scrolled to a certain point. So I set up the test:

```
describe("SingleJob page", function() {

    beforeEach(function() {

        loadFixtures('my_fixture.html');
    });


    it("panel sticks to top when page scrolled down", function() {

        spyOn(mycompany.singleJobTestable.LozengesPanel, "makeFixed");

        window.scroll(0,1000);

           expect(mycompany.singleJobTestable.LozengesPanel.makeFixed).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

But the test fails, all I get is `Expected spy makeFixed to have been called.`
How can I trigger window scroll so I can test methods inside of this callback?

EDIT:

Finally it all makes sense.. It seems that scroll event was put in a tasks queue only to be executed after the current thread finishes. Adding $(window).trigger("scroll"); did the trick. I posted short blog post about it that explains the issue http://spirytoos.blogspot.com.au/2014/02/testing-windowscroll-with-qunitjasmine.html

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This answer does not satisfy the question. See the comments for the reason.

Actually, it looks like you are triggering the scroll event from your Jasmine spec. I tried very similar code, which I include below. However, my `expect` still fails, like yours (I'm still getting familiar with Jasmine, so I can't explain with certainty why that is).

```
var fun = {
    scrollEventCallback: function() {
        console.log('scroll event triggered');
    }
};
$(window).on('scroll', fun.scrollEventCallback);

describe("A test suite", function() {

    it("should trigger f", function() {
        spyOn(fun, "scrollEventCallback");
        $(window).trigger('scroll'); // my callback function is executed because it logs to the console
       expect(fun.scrollEventCallback).toHaveBeenCalled(); // this fails anyway
    });
});
```

Comment: Does it work if you change $(window).on('scroll', fun.scrollEventCallback); to $(window).on('scroll', function(){ fun.scrollEventCallback();}); ?

Comment: When I try that I get something different! Nothing is logged to the console and the `expect` assertion succeeds. I see why that is: in my code `fun.scrollEventCallback` is dereferenced to the original, anonymous function definition. On other hand, the call inside `function() { fun.scrollEventCallback(); }` resolves to the spy stub implementation when it is triggered because the spyOn() method has since modified the reference of fun.scrollEventCallback. So my answer is not helpful.

Comment: Yep, thats what I thought.. jasmine's SpyOn method changes fun.scrollEventCallback, but only after jquery has already bound to the original. Using .andCallThrough() on the spy would get your console.log working again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your `window.scroll(0, 1000)` is not actually pushing the viewport low enough to trigger your `Lozenges.makeFixed()` call. That would be the case if the page (your fixture, I think) wasn't long and it didn't actually have anywhere to scroll.

Also, I got code similar to your provided code to work. The `expect(...)` succeeds. It is pasted below.

```
var LozengesPanel = {
    makeFixed: function() {
        console.log('makeFixed was called with its original function definition');
    }
};

$(window).on("scroll.singleJob",function(e) {
    LozengesPanel.makeFixed();
});

describe("A test suite", function() {
    it("should trigger callback", function() {
        spyOn(LozengesPanel, "makeFixed");
        $(window).trigger('scroll'); // nothing is logged to the console
        expect(LozengesPanel.makeFixed).toHaveBeenCalled(); // succeeds
    });
});
```